# ¿En que fichero/dirección está almacenada una base de datos local con Room Database?

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

Tengo una base de datos local con Room Database en un emulador Android 8.0, quiero saber donde está alojada localmente para gestionarla como un archivo y verificar lo que contiene sin tener que estar haciendo Logs, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma en la que puedes ver la localización de tu BD es mediante las siguiente linea en la cual guardas en un string la ruta donde esta localizado el fichero .db

```
String actualtDBPath=getDatabasePath("tuBaseDatos.db").getAbsolutePath();
```

Pero normalmente tus base de datos se encontrará en la siguiente ruta, para ello debes abrir la pestaña del menu '`Device File explorer`':

```
data/data/your-application-package/databases
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!